# How can I link to MSDN/official documentation from my C# XML documentation comments?

Tags: msdn, ndoc, xml-documentation

Given an XML comment on a class something like this:

```
///<summary>Handles the AuthenticateRequest event in the ASP.NET page request lifecycle to authenticate users.</summary>
///<remarks>
///<para>This module will authenticate users based on cookies, form posts, or an impersonation request from the  admin system.</para>
///<para>If authentication succeeds, both the <see cref="System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal" /> and the <see cref="System.Web.HttpContext.User"/> property are set to an instance of <see cref="MyPrincipal"/> representing the authenticated user.</para>
///</remarks>
```

How can I get the references to `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `System.Web.HttpContext.User` to link to the appropriate pages in the framework documentation?

Comment: What software are you using to process your XML documentation into real help pages?

Comment: Docu - https://github.com/jagregory/docu

Answer (score 2):

You can use `href` tag to link to MSDN (or any other source for that matter) and do something like this:

```
... both the <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx">System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal</see>...
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/msdn-url-cheatsheet/) url, the msdn url cheatsheet

and these two experiments applying the things learned from the cheatsheet

link to 1.1 version of frameworkclass

[System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal%28v=vs.71%29)

link to 4.0 version of frameworkclass

[System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal%28v=vs.100%29)

Comment: Sad thing is, this only seems to work for non-generic types. Generic types have a mangled ID.